# Julia DataFrame: the best way to replace the data in DataFrame?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am considering what is the best way to replace the data in DataFrame.
I mean

1. df1 exists like this

```
        Row │ c_name    t_name       a_number
            │ String      Any         Int64
       ─────┼──────────────────────────────────
          1 │ f1.id    ["f1"]           2
          2 │ f2.name  ["f2"]           2
          3 │ f.id     ["f","f2"]       1
          4 │ f.name   ["f"]            1
          5 │ f3.id    ["f3","f"]       1
```

2. Other df2 exists like this,

```
        Row │ t_name
            │ String
       ─────┼───────────
          1 │ f
          2 │ f1
          3 │ f2
          4 │ f3
```

3. Make matching df1.t_name & df2.t_name, then df1.t_name is replaced by df2 Row number of the same t_name in df2,  ex. f->1, f1->2...

```
        Row │ c_name    t_name      a_number
            │ String      Any         Int64
       ─────┼──────────────────────────────────
          1 │ f1.id    [2]             2
          2 │ f2.name  [3]             2
          3 │ f.id     [1,3]           1
          4 │ f.name   [1]             1
          5 │ f3.id    [4,1]           1
```

I think it can be make with iteration but seems silly. Use join? but hard to replace them with Row number.
Julia DataFrame may have a smarter way.

I am appreciated if you noticed it to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary for this:

```
@assert allunique(df2.t_name)
d = Dict(df2.t_name .=> axes(df2, 1)
df1.t_name = [getindex.(Ref(d), v) for x in df1.t_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, Thank you so much Ph. Kaminski again. This is totaly elegant code that I wanted.
It worked perfectly, however I have to correct it a little bit for the future similar questioners. :^)

```
d = Dict(df2.t_name .=> axes(df2, 1) )                     <- add ")" after axes()
df1.t_name = [getindex.(Ref(d), x) for x in df1.t_name]    <- change "v" to "x"
```

And this code works fine because df2.t_name is perfectly unique.

Jeszcze raz dziękuję, Dr. Kamiński

Comment: I believe you can edit the existing Answer, if the code is not logically different.